# Container Registry not displaying Cloud Storage Bucket Docker images

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm the owner of a project, and have a co-worker who created all of the docker images for the project, which are available under the Container Registry within the Google Developer's Console. The images can be viewed in the Registry when he logs in, but I don't see anything.

What's stranger is that the co-worker is unable to see any images within the Google Cloud Storage Bucket, but I can see all of the Docker images.

What's supposed to be visible to both of us isn't lining-up between the Registry and the Cloud Bucket.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: What permissions are provided to your co-worker for your project ? For more infomation on project member permissions you can refer to this link (https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#differentroles). Can you check the cloud storage ACLs (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en) to see if your co-worker has access to image bucket ?

Comment: My co-worker has "Can edit" permissions for the project (I have "Is owner"). On the particular bucket, permissions on it state that Project (Entity) editors (Name) is an Owner (Access). 

I just checked, and now the co-worker is able to see the images in the cloud storage bucket. However, I still don't see any entries under the Container Registry (when I am logged in).

Comment: @DexterJ. Is your user added to the ocker user group ? you can add it by running this command: sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}. Once done, log out and back in and try.

Comment: @DexterJ. I added the comment as answer if possible to mark it as the good answer so others can benefit from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the user to the docker user group by running the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}
```